# Error con {% trans %} en plantilla django

Tags: django, django-templates

Tengo una template de django que quiero traducir un valor que es variable, pues está dentro de un for.

La línea es la siguiente: {{ item.title }}
Quiero traducir lo que hay dentro de esa variable de la template.

Lo que hice fue {{ {% trans 'item.title' %} }} y después en el archivo django.po lo siguiente:

```
#: templates/tittle.html:10 (línea en la que se encuentra la variable a traducir)
msgid "Titulo"
msgstr "Tittle"

#: templates/tittle.html:10
msgid "Titulo2"
msgstr "Tittle2"
```

Y así para todos los caso del for.
Esto no me funciona. Por lo que pregunto lo que estoy haciendo mal, o si existe alguna otra forma de realizarlo.

Muchas gracias de antemano.

Comment: Posible duplicado de [Traducción Sitetree en Django](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/190359/traducci%c3%b3n-sitetree-en-django)

Comment: Ya solo existe esta pregunta.

Comment: Ya intentaste hacer una traducción de la variable antes de que llegue a tu template? es decir, meramente del lado del archivo de python?